# Is it possible to subselect in overlaps clause in postgres 9.1?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

My database structure is as follows:

I have scheduletimes which have a classtime. Each scheduletime has a tclass associated with it that has a duration. I would normally use a join of some sort to grab the duration, however, since I am using the overlaps comparison in postgres I am not sure if this is possible. The query would look something like this...

```
Select (scheduletimes.classtime, scheduletimes.classtime + interval 
(select duration from tclasses where tclass.id = scheduletimes.tclass_id) minutes) OVERLAPS 
(06:50:00, 07:20:00) from schedules where
day = 1 and
schedule_id = 14;
```

Comment: Next time, please try to provide example tables and take more care in crafting your sample query.  Your table names don't match between one part of the query and another, and your time literals aren't in proper format, so you're putting a big burden on someone who wants to help you to sort out what you really mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery, but in your example you are mixing the literal format with a value from a column, which won't work.  And generally it is better to `JOIN` rather than to use a subquery, so you might want something like this:

```
SELECT
    scheduletimes.*,
    (scheduletimes.classtime, scheduletimes.classtime
         + (interval '1 minute' * tclasses.duration))
       OVERLAPS (time '06:50:00', time '07:20:00')
  FROM scheduletimes
  JOIN tclasses ON tclasses.id = scheduletimes.tclass_id
  WHERE day = 1
    AND schedule_id = 14;
```